# vlc player scrambled audio after skipping through a movie

Tags: sound, vlc

When I watch a movie in `vlc` and I fast forward or backward the sound suddenly becomes very creaky, it sounds hollow and scrambled, after a few minutes it goes away.

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10. and before that I had xubuntu, then I had the same problem. `totem` works fine.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Greetings
mies

Comment: Does this apply to all files you are trying to play back? What hardware do you use? How is the CPU load during this event? Please edit your question to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

Edit the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

Replace the line:

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

With:

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Restart your computer.

Comment: he Karolsojko, thanks for your response, it was very useful, it totally fixed it.
greetings
mies